# Can I send the error response I get from an Ajax call to my custom error view, and if so is it a good idea?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am wondering if I can send the error response I get from an Ajax call to my custom error view in MVC5.

Here is my very basic custom error view, which works for my controller error handling:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

@{
    // get innermost exception
    var e = Model.Exception;
    while (e.InnerException != null)
    {
        e = e.InnerException;
    }
}

@e.Message
<br />
@Model.Exception.StackTrace
```

If I have an ajax call, I can do something like:

```
$.ajax
({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function() { /* do successful stuff */ },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert("Code:  " + jqXHR.status + "\n\nStatus:  " + jqXHR.textStatus + "\n\nError:  " + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

But is there a good clean way to take that jqXHR and represent it with my error view?  I thought about having the error function submit another call to the controller to throw a new error with the responseText but wasn't sure that was a good idea.. what if THAT action fails somehow?

Thank you in advance for any help and advice!

Comment: Do you want to redirect to that error view, or just update the existing page with the html of that error view?

Comment: I want to redirect to that error view.

Comment: Since your making an ajax call, you only option would be to use `location.href=...` in the callback to redirect to a method that throws the same exception

Comment: That's what I wondered.  Is it a bad idea to do that for any reason?

Comment: Performance would not be great. I think that your initial method that threw the exception would need to pass back the typeof exception (as a `string`) so you could pass it to the other method, and in that one use reflection to initialize and throw that exception. But I suspect there would be issues trying to display inner exceptions because you would need to pass that as well (and apart from the ugly query string, you could exceed the query string limit and throw an different exception)

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  Is there a way to accept your comments as the answer?

Comment: I did not consider it an answer, just some comments :)